# Can minidumps immediately reveal where in my own code a failure occurred?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, minidump

Suppose that my Windows application crashes with some `throw std::runtime_error` and generates a minidump (.dmp) with WER. When I open this minidump in Visual Studio for debugging, I am not immediately taken to the problematic line in code that threw the exception, but have to work through the call stack and back-track the problem, starting inside some Microsoft DLL like *ucrtbased.dll*. This is unlike if I start the application in debug mode, where the debugger will immediately break at the line that throws the exception, in my own code.

Is it possible to debug minidumps such that I can immediately know where in *my own code* the problem was, i.e. can I be taken directly to the problematic line that caused the crash, similar to what the debugger would do?

Comment: There's a "Just My Code" feature in VS, but i don't know if this does anything when debugging a dump file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2022